# rails form_for mongoid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, form-for

Hi i have a simple form for updating a user's account here is my controller

```
def edit
  @users = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

here is my view

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>

<%= f.label :first_name %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :name  ,:value => @users.name%><br />

<%= f.label :last_name %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :lname  ,:value => @users.lname%><br />

<%= f.label :email %> <br />
<%= f.email_field :email  ,:value => @users.email%><br />

<%= f.label :id %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :id  ,:value => @users.id%><br />

<br />
<%= f.submit ({:confirm => "Are you sure?"}) %>
<% end %>
```

when i click submit i get the following mongoid error

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in UsersController#edit
```

Problem:
  Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.

Summary:
  Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided.

Resolution:
  Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.

I'm fairly novice with rails and this is my first stab with mongoDB. Any input would help, Thank you.

Comment: .. try using <%= form_for @users do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this form

```
<%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>
   ...
   ...
<% end %>
```

The error comes because you are using `:user` that `invalid find` in your `user controller`